# no se ve la imagen por URL css ::before

Tags: html, css, login

Buen día!, soy nuevo tanto en la programación como en esta comunidad. Hoy estoy intentando colocar una imagen PNG dentro del campo de input al lado del placeholder. Deseo hacerlo mediante CSS. Muchas gracias!

```css
.login-div__password {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: inset 8px 8px 8px #cbced1, inset -8px -8px 8px #fff;
    }
    
    .login-div__password::before {
      display: block;
      content: "";
      background-image: url(../img/pass.png);
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="login-div__password" placeholder="Texto">
```

Comment: ¿Y este código funciona o que resultado da?

Comment: nono, no se logra ver la imagen o icono antes del placeholder. nisiquiera aparece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible agregar imagen de fondo a un input usando la propiedad `:before`, en este caso lo recomendable seria ingresar todo en un contenedor y agregar una imagen en posición `absolute`, para que se sobreponga al input, luego con css das los estilos según sea necesario, por ejemplo:

```css
.contenedor-input {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .login-div__password {
            width: 100%;
            height: 30px;
            padding-left: 40px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        img.input-icon {
            width: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 5px;
            height: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-input">
        <img class="input-icon" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/email-1818372-1541480.png">
        <input type="text" class="login-div__password" placeholder="Insertar Email">
    </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder! duda solucionada!